# (Javascript) How do you ignore lower/upper case being registered in search bars when searching for a specific item

Tags: javascript, search, case-sensitive, uppercase, lowercase

I am tasked with constructing a search engine for a website that displays various pictures that all have different titles. Ie, `"Pictures of birds"`, `"Flying birds"`, `"Green Birds"`. As of now when I type in `"birds"` only the first two results will display.
How can I ignore case sensitive searches, so that when a user types in `"birds"` all three searches will come up.

I hear converting the string to say all uppercase/lowercase could ignore it. However, I am unfamiliar with exactly how I would implement this.
As of now I have this line of code within my function:

```
var str = document.getElementById('searchTxt').value;

var upper = str.toUpperCase();
console.log(str);
```

I am trying to print the value in the variable to the `console`. Nothing is working and on the console only 2 objects are defined.
If someone could explain what I would need to do to get my code functioning, i'd be grateful.

Comment: Your variable `upper` should be written to the `console`, not the `str` variable.  `toUpperCase` and most (if not all) of the Javascript string functions return the result rather than modifying the original.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the unconverted string to the console.

```
console.log(upper);
```

should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. My code stands now as:                     var upper = str.toUpperCase();
 console.log(upper);            However, it's still not displaying all three pictures. I'm figuring somewhere else in the code must be the problem.

Comment: You need to do it on both sides.